# Using Jquery fullscreen background plugin with multiple backgrounds on one page

Tags: jquery, background-image, fullscreen

I already have a Jquery slider with left and right arrows for content that uses anchors and hashes so all of the web content (pages) are on one html page.  I need to have full screen backgrounds and I got something working using CSS but it doesn't show the whole image and adds vertical scroll bars which wasn't acceptable, that version is here:
ilandeistudio.com

So I am trying a different method using Jquery:
http://code.ttcon.hu/fullscrn/#!/instructions

I can get this working but I do not know how to get it to work with the sliders/multiple backgrounds.  The instructions say that you can change the background later just call the setImage method:

```
fullScr.setImage("images/bg_about1.jpg");
```

I am not really sure how to do this or where exactly it should go.  I made a test page here:
http://www.ilandeistudio.com/index06.html

When you click the right arrow I want it to change to the next background like it does on the first link I posted ilandeistudio.com

Answer (score 0):

I checked a fiddler for this html.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14028956/index06.html.txt

```
<script type="text/javascript">
dojo.require("dojo.NodeList-manipulate");
dojo.require("ttcon.fullscrn");
dojo.ready(function() {
    var fullScr = new ttcon.fullscrn({
      image: "images/bg_home1.jpg"
    });
    dojo.query(".special-anchor").onclick(function(){
      if(/home/.test(location.hash)){
        fullScr.setImage("images/bg_home1.jpg");
        return;
      }
      if(/about/.test(location.hash)){
        fullScr.setImage("images/bg_about1.jpg");
        return;
      }
    });
});
</script>
```

Read reference & documentation.

- http://code.ttcon.hu/fullscrn/#!/instructions
- https://github.com/tcsizmadia/fullscrn
- http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.7/dojo/NodeList

Why are there so many JavaScript Library used :(

Comment: yes, I already read the directions, and I don't understand them that is why I posted, new to jquery but thanks for responding

Comment: I did try this with the index06.html test page but it fades in with a white instead of sliding like the current solution.  I'm trying to add the slide, not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Can be accomplished without using the dojo toolkit or the fullscrn plugin.

1. Place an img into a div, sized to the window, position fixed, and set z-index:-1
2. Use jQuery UI $.hide() and $.show() to slide in the background in and out.
3. Change img src using jQuery $.attr()

Example:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    i=0;j=0;
    $("#sin").click(function(event) {
        if (i = i ? 0 : 1) $("#bgimg").show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
        else $("#bgimg").hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
    });
    $("#changebg").click(function(event) {
        bgs = ['http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png', 'http://col.stc.s-msn.com/br/sc/i/icons/BING_websearch_2.jpg'];
        $("#bgimg").attr('src', bgs[j = j ? 0 : 1]);
    });
});
</script>
<style>
#bg{z-index:-1;position:fixed;top:0;left:0;height:100%;width:100%;}
#bgimg{height:100%;width:100%;}
</style>
<button id="sin">Slide</button><button id="changebg">Change bg</button>

<div id="bg"><img src="http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" id="bgimg" /></div>
```

Comment: thank you so much for the response, but I am a little confused.  I already have a very mice Jquery plugin (not the dojo) for sldiing the content using hashes/anchors.  The website just isn't showing and hiding backgrounds, there is also text, other images, whole web pages - you can see the working version at the link above.  I just need to know how to use this: fullScr.setImage("images/bg_about1.jpg");

Comment: @user1269988 A possible solution may be to relocate the plugin-generated background div into your slider div.  You'll have to set some CSS attributes to keep it behind your content. Heres a start: `<style>#fullscrn-bg{z-index:-1;position:static;top:0;left:0;height:100%;width:100%;}</style>` and `$("#fullscrn-bg").appendTo(".slider");`